# How to use child table column in org.hibernate.annotations.Formula

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I need to concat some columns from both parent and child table using `@Formula`
Here is the Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent1")
public class Parent1 implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private BigInteger id;

  @Column(name = "childId")
  private BigInteger childId;
  
  @Column(name = "col1")
  private String col1;
  
  @Column(name = "col2")
  private String col2;
  
  @Formula("CONCAT_WS(' ',Parent2.child_colm,col1,col2)")
  private String combinedName;
  
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "childId")
  private Parent2 parent2;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "parent2")
public class Parent2 implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "childId")
  private BigInteger childId;
  
  @Column(name = "child_colm")
  private String child_colm;

}
```

While giving like this it returns `Unknown column 'Parent2.child_colm'`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you instead of using `@Formula` here just write the following method:

```java
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "parent1")
public class Parent1 implements Serializable {

   @Transient
   public String getCombinedName() {
      return Stream.of(parent2.child_colm, col1, col2)
          .filter(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty())
          .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
   }
}
```

The `@Transient` [annotation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Transient.html) is used to specify that a given entity attribute should not be persisted.